# Set Cursor on the final record in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using a `ListView` to show records. The user can refresh the `ListView` to add more records on the `ListView`.I need to show the cursor to the last record of the `ListView` before the `ListView` was refreshed.

The `ListView` is getting refreshed dynamically, but it is showing the topmost record. I wish to show it on to the first record after it has refreshed.

I have tried implementing this logic,

```
if(histroyRefreshed){
                int index = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
                View v = getListView().getChildAt(0);
                int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

                // ...

                // restore
                getListView().setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
            }
```

Comment: and what result do you get ?

Comment: it is showing the topmost record. I wish to show it on to the first record after it has refreshed.

Comment: you should probably compute the 'index' variable (and store it) before refreshing the list, otherwise it will always be 0 (first item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getListView().setSelection(location);
```

This sets the location to the last record,before history is refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Keep your item id into a local field, once you have updated your list view, use your pre-stored id to find out where it is.